# Can't find the canonical question for a duplicate

Tags: discussion

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534318/dual-os-problem-with-booting) about dual-booting and windows not being recognized by Grub, which I'm fairly certain is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find the canonical question that actually answers it, just a whole bunch of similar questions without answers that are often marked as duplicates of some other question equally without answer (or only limited useful ones).

Does anyone know a question that has some extensive answers, so we can mark it as a duplicate of that question?

P.S. I would normally ask this question in the chat, but it never logs me in, but that's a different issue;)

Comment: This [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118948/dual-boot-linux-windows-grub) contains a link [there](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) which should be enough for dual-boot issues. Sadly, I can find a "good" answer either, except this one, which is basically a link-only answer.

Comment: Because it basically don't exist. There are many variables involved in such cases that there isn't a canonical response (aka answer) that would fix them all. Treating them separately might seems counterproductive but I prefer that, than use a single question as dumping ground burying good information along with the bad and confusing one.